# Is there justifying strings to left and right statements in Turbo Pascal?

Tags: pascal, qbasic

I searched in Turbo Pascal 6 the complete reference for "rset" and "lset" - statements of QB 4.5 for justifying strings inside their variables bytes - equivalents in Turbo Pascal and found no result as if Turbo Pascal doesn't need these statements or Turbo Pascal is always justifying strings to left. Is this true?

Comment: `Turbo Pascal is always justifying strings to left` - in what context, when writing out to console or text file?

Comment: I'm searching for justifying in string variables bytes and files

Comment: Left-padding a string with spaces to a certain width can be done with something like `function LeftPad(const s: string; len: Integer): string; begin Result := s; while length(Result) < len do Result := ' ' + Result; end;` (line-breaks not included).

Comment: But, we can't do it actually in bytes with moving the string to the last bytes of the variable or file buffer, we need to use spaces.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your comment. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I mean in QB 4.5 "rset" statement for example is justifying the string value to the most right bytes in the variable, I think it doesn't put spaces in left bytes, but maybe null character or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Turbo Pascal 6.0 the `string` type reserves 256 bytes of memory.

```
s: string;
```

The memory layout is that the first byte (value 0..255) indicates the length of the string. The following bytes hold the characters, **always left aligned**.

A variation of the previous is that you can declare string variables with a maximum length, like f.ex.

```
s: string[10];
```

This example will reserve 11 bytes of memory. Again the first byte indicates length of the actual string (value in this case 0..10).

The memory content after a statement like

```
s := 'test';
```

will be

```
4, 't', 'e', 's', 't', #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0
```

There is no statement to modify the character allocation to right align the character data (like RSET in QBasic).

However, in theory, you may precede a string with a series of null characters, e.g `s :=#0#0#0#0#0#0+'test';`, to achieve a similar effect, but the length will become the length of the string variable.

```
10, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, 't', 'e', 's', 't'
```

The null chars are in this case part of the string, and this might be problematic. A null char might be taken for the end of the string. Also, as the null chars might be omitted by e.g. a printing procedure in some case and not in other cases. This could lead to misalignment of data in printouts, or other.